# What does quantised mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, discrete

I was reading an article (forgot the link) but it said

> "The energy levels of the electron in a hydrogen atom are quantised".

What do they mean by the term quantised?

Comment: My answer here might help https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/538930/

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a question about physics and not the English language, since the answer [can be found in a dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quantize).and the word has been used in this sense outside of its origin in quantum physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind that definition comes at it from the wrong direction. It implies we get to decide how much we consider measurable. Really it's as simple as counting whole apples as opposed to counting half apples or bushels of apples. An apple is an apple regardless of what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we mean by quantise is **discrete**. You know for example that the energy of a free particle is a continuous value of the impulse $$E = \frac{p^2}{2m}$$ The energy of the electrons in the hydrogen atom is not a continuous function of anything, instead takes on discrete values depending on an integer $n$ which we call *energy level*. The energy levels of the hydrogen atom are evaluated in the quantum theory and are given by $$E_n = -\frac{E_0}{n^2}$$ where $E_0 = 13.6$ eV. There's no way for an electron in the hydrogen atom to have an energy between two successive levels like $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Quantized means *discrete*, i.e. coming in fixed portions, called *quanta* (singular - *quantum*).

Answer (score 1):

It means that electrons can only possess certain fixed energies and have no values in between those levels, no continuum of energies.